# natural join and minus operator

Tags: sql, oracle, join

[image: Question and expected output]

[image: ERD]

Hi I'm trying to figure out the question below.

*It is RRSP season and the bank is looking to promote their RRSPs. Produce a list of all customers who have at least one type of account with us but who do not currently have an RRSP account. Again do NOT use hard-coded the account_type codes instead use the account descriptions. Solve using natural join.*

I'm pretty sure I need to use MINUS operator in order to solve the question.
This is what I have so far. 
I have attached expected output for the question.

```
SELECT surname "Last", 
       first_name "First" 
FROM wgb_customer wc 
NATURAL JOIN wgb_account wa 
NATURAL JOIN wgb_account_type wat 
MINUS 
SELECT surname, 
       first_name 
FROM wgb_account_type wat 
NATURAL JOIN wgb_account wa 
NATURAL JOIN wgb_customer wc 
ORDER BY 1;
```

However, it says no rows selected.
Please help!

Comment: Post the question and not the image.

Comment: Ugh! I understand this is a learning exercise, but please, don't ever use Natural Joins in production code; if you were to add (or remove) a column in a table used in a natural join that happened to match the name of a column in the table being joined to, voila, you've just changed the join. Natural joins are very dangerous, IMO; it's much better to explicitly state the join columns. Not only do you avoid the join conditions unexpectedly changing, you also give much more information to anyone (including you, in 6 months time) reading/amending the query!

Comment: Don't the two subqueries select the same thing? I think you want [select all the customers] `MINUS` [select only those accounts whose type is RRSP]. And I'm not sure that `MINUS` is the best way. But you'd need to post the data model for anyone to be able to give a definite idea.

Comment: Please read [mcve] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'--show what sub-problems you can do & how you are combining them. Don't just dump wrong code. Please [use text, not images/links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097), for text (including code, tables & ERDs). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. PS Constraints, including FKs, are not needed to query. What matters is what tables mean--what a row says when in a table.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `exists` and `not exists`:

```
SELECT wc.*
FROM wgb_customer wc 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM wgb_account wa JOIN
                   wgb_account_type wat 
                   ON wat.account_type = wa.account_type
              WHERE wat.account_type <> 'RRSP'
             ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM wgb_account wa JOIN
                       wgb_account_type wat 
                       ON wat.account_type = wa.account_type
                  WHERE wat.account_type = 'RRSP'
                 ) ;
```

I would advise you to never use `natural join` and to simply forget that it exists at all.  Always explicitly list the join conditions!

Comment: Spec says, "Solve using natural join." :)

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . And that is really, really bad advice.  The OP should learn how to write good SQL code.

Comment: If the exam tests you on something you don't believe in, don't take the course. If your principles prevent you from satisfying the spec, don't bid on the job. If you don't think the OP is asking the right question, don't answer it. That's my good advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a search condition for RRSP accounts e.g.

```
SELECT surname, 
       first_name 
FROM wgb_customer 
NATURAL JOIN wgb_account 
MINUS 
SELECT surname, 
       first_name 
FROM wgb_account_type 
NATURAL JOIN wgb_account 
NATURAL JOIN wgb_customer
WHERE Account_description = 'RRSP'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using correlated subquery

```
SELECT surname "Last", first_name "First" 
FROM wgb_customer wc JOIN wgb_account wa  on wc.customerNumber=wa.customerNumber
JOIN wgb_account_type wat on wa.account_type=wat.account_type
where not exists 
    (select 1 from wgb_account_type wat1 where wat.account_type=wat1.account_type 
      and wat1.account_type='RRSP')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading that question correctly, then you are using the wrong kind of natural join, and should look at using an outer natural join.This also means you will not need the minus keyword.

You can go to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BABBAGAH) for more information on the joins.

The one line i want to point out from that documentation is that a natural join will be treated as a "INNER" join. which means the key your common columns are checking for will have to exist in both tables. what you want is something where it only exists in one table hence the Outer join. Good Luck!